# Multi wording site as opposed to multi language, can gettext solve that too?

Tags: php, multilingual, gettext

I have a site which targets several industries.
So in one industry the manager would be called "department head" and in the other "inspector".
Can I solve this issue with gettext, as it is in a way a multi linguistic problem.

Comment: I think this is against many search engine's terms and conditions.

Comment: @Martin Bean: Does Itay have some contract with search engines he must comply or something? I've built differently worded sites before (cart in USA becomes basket in Europe).

Comment: Odd words would be OK, but I would have thought tailoring whole pages of content to certain groups of people would be deemed shady?

Comment: @Martin Bean I don't really care about search engines. The pages I do need them to index are optimized for SEO and do not have this problem of multi linguality as each industry has different content attached to it.

Comment: A bit shady, but it's not my site...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this with gettext even if the site will be multilanguage.
On the page load you need to define the language this time "dep. head" or "inspector".

Comment: Not sure I understood you. Both of those wordings are of the same LOCALE

Comment: It's no problem. Based on the requested industry you load the related "language" file which isn't a real language but a different style.

Comment: so I can call the locale what ever I want?

Comment: i don't see any restriction at setlocale's documentation. I tried to set a fictional language and it doesn't throw an error. And finally: you can set any unused (real) language if everything else fails. :)